# Create number of new class objects from dictionary count

Tags: c#, .net, oop, collections

```
int proprtyCount = dictionary.Keys.Count;

 foreach (KeyValuePair<object, object> pair in dictionary)
{
     ClassCustom obj1 =new ClassCustom(pair.Key, pair.Value);
}
```

I need to create number objects using dictionary.keys.count and pass those objects to some collection class.

i have to pass objects like below to collection (eg.dictionary key count is 3 in this case)

```
SomeCollection collection =new SomeCollection(obj1,obj2,obj3);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you assign it to a list?

```
int proprtyCount = dictionary.Keys.Count;
var classCustomList = new List<ClassCustom>();
foreach (KeyValuePair<object, object> pair in dictionary)
{
     classCustomList.Add(new ClassCustom(pair.Key, pair.Value));
}

SomeCollection collection = new SomeCollection(classCustomList);
```

Have the SomeCollection class initialize a list of type `classCustomList` in it's constructor.

Update: If it's some sort of collection class, maybe try doing something similar to

```
int proprtyCount = dictionary.Keys.Count;
var conditions = new PropertyCondition[propertyCount];
int index = 0;
foreach (KeyValuePair<object, object> pair in dictionary)
{
    conditions[i] = new PropertyCondition(pair.Key, pair.Value));
    index++;
}

var conditionEnabledButtons = new AndCondition(conditions);
```

There's an overload with type array

Eg.

```
var conditions = new PropertyCondition[3];
conditions[0] = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.IsEnabledProperty, true);
conditions[1] = new PropertyCondition(AutomationElement.ControlTypeProperty, ControlType.Button);
var conditionEnabledButtons = new AndCondition(conditions);
```

Comment: SomeCollection class accepts only in ClassCustom format

Comment: so list is not useful in this case

Comment: I don't understand. Why don't you post the code for your SomeCollection class. You can always change the constructor rather than passing in objects of type ClassCustom. 

You don't know the number of the dictionary key count, so you can't initialize your SomeCollection the way you're currently doing.

Comment: its a microsoft Automation class i cant change

Comment: Now I see. I thought SomeCollection was a custom class you made. Next time, maybe post the actual Microsoft class you're using.


Regardless, if it's some sort of collection class, there should be an Add or a similar function.
Otherwise you might want to look into another overload that accepts a collection of your ClassCustom. Why don't you tell me what collection class you're using.

Comment: i need to create PropertyCondition class and pass to AndCondition check below link

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.automation.andcondition.andcondition(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Updated my answer. There's an overload that accepts of type array. I've updated my original answer, and I added an extra snippet.